# How to open .rar file in fedora 23

Tags: linux, fedora, rar

I am using fedora 23 64 bit. I have downloaded some `.rar` files.

After googling I have found solutions suggesting that using `unrar` they can be opened.

But I am unable to install `unrar`. I have tried the following steps after googling to install but failed.

#### Solution 1:

For free-release:

```
su -c 'yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'
```

For nonfree-release:

```
su -c 'yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree`/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'`
```

To install `unrar`:

Run the following command in terminal and type the password for the user, when prompted.

```
sudo yum install unrar
```

#### Solution 2:

```
# wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
# rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm

yum install unrar
```

But nothing is working. My system is up to date.

How can I open `.rar` files in fedora?

Comment: Maybe this?...https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/69533/unrar-dont-work-on-fedora-22/

Comment: When you say it "failed" or "nothing is working", what exactly _is_ happening? What do you expect to happen, and what is the actual result?

Comment: @mattdm just simply no package found....

Comment: Does that package exist in the repository you added?

Comment: Sorry i dont know how to check....the existence of package

Comment: The enabling of the "nonfree" repository for Fedora has since changed a bit. See: [Enabling the RPM Fusion repositories](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/setup_rpmfusion/). Enable both _free_ and _nonfree_ repositories (the latter holds package `unrar`) according to instructions. Then call `dnf install unrar`. Execute `rpm --query --queryformat "%{VENDOR}; %{VERSION}; %{LICENSE}\n" unrar` to get the string `RPM Fusion; 6.0.3; Freeware with further limitations`. Take a look at the license: `less /usr/share/licenses/unrar/license.txt`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Install the `unar` package.

```
$ dnf info unar
...
Name        : unar
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 0
Version     : 1.10.1
Release     : 1.fc24
Size        : 4.6 M
Repo        : @System
From repo   : updates
Summary     : Multi-format extractor
URL         : http://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline
License     : LGPLv2+
Description : The command-line utilities lsar and unar are capable of listing
            : and extracting files respectively in several formats including
            : RARv3. unar can serve as a free and open source replacement of
            : unrar.
$ sudo dnf install unar
```

The Archive Manager (gui application) will be able to open `.rar` files.

Answer (score 3):

.rar is the extension used by Winrar to compress files and they are like Zip files but in a different format. Many other programs can decompress it and you should download the free 7-Zip which is amongst the best from here http://www.7-zip.org/download.html, choose your flavor of operating system in your case Fedora, install and use that to unrar your file

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 25 Xfce:

```
sudo dnf install https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm
sudo dnf install unrar
```

Comment: Can you explain more not just the instruction